# "go build ./..." cannot find package

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I know internet full of similar issues and I tried all of suggested solutions, but can't figure out it at least 2 days.

I trying to deploy little Go server I using IntelliJ IDEA and it works great, it can build/run my code, but if I use terminal as example:

```
go build ./...
```

I see something like that:

```
OS-X-Dennis:backend denis$ go build ./...
out/production/mypocket_backend/server.go:4:2: cannot find package "api.jwt.auth/routers" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/api.jwt.auth/routers (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/denis/Programming/Golang/src/api.jwt.auth/routers (from $GOPATH)
```

**OS X 10.11.2, IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1

$GOPATH = "Users/denis/Programming/Golang"

$GOROOT = "/usr/local/go"

$PATH = "$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"**

These paths are correct?

Here is my work structure:

```
/Golang/
 .bin/
 .pkg/
    .darwin-amd64/
         .//other folders/
 .src/
     .github.com/
     .backend/ //project's source
           /src
              /api.jwt.auth/
                //source code
           .server.go - file with main func
          //other files as example .gitignore
     .//other folders//
```

Here is my screen of main file and whole project-structure:
[image]

I see that logs show me wrong path to my project.

```
 now
 /Users/denis/Programming/Golang/src/api.jwt.auth/routers
should
 /Users/denis/Programming/Golang/src/backend/src/api.jwt.auth/routers
```

I don't know where I should correct this path.

Comment: Is the backend folder the source to your project or what is that?  All packages that are included in your project need to be in the src folder of your GOPATH.  I would bet your folder structure is different locally than it is on your server

Comment: how do you import `api.jwt.auth` package? i have a strong feeling that you didn't import correctly.

Comment: it's should be `import "backend/src/api.jwt.auth"`, not `api.jwt.auth`.

Comment: @nevets, I edit my question, also I have edit my import but it didn't help

Comment: @tier1, yes it's a source project dir, all dependencies which needed to project included in GOPATH/src.

Comment: @nevets, intellij builds and runs project

Comment: it seems your server is within `api.jwt.auth` folder :s have you tried `go build ./...` within `backend/src` and ` backend/src/api.jwt.auth`?

Comment: @nevets, yes, I have tried, it shows the same issue, do you have assumptions why it adds src/api.jwt.auth to my GOPATH) sorry if I ask very fundamental questions, my golang experience is too small

Comment: hmmm, i'm afraid intellij automatically add your current folder into PATH, so that it could find `api.jwt.auth` :s i'm not using intellij so i could not confirm thought :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108189/discussion-between-nevets-and-denis-zinkovskiy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GOPATH can have multiple directories in it.

If you truly want your `backend` directory to be a path of some of your Go libraries, in addition to your existing path of `/Users/denis/Programming/Golang` you can set your GOPATH to: `/Users/denis/Programming/Golang:/Users/denis/Programming/Golang/src/backend`

This will cause import statements to search for source files in both the `/Users/denis/Programming/Golang/src` directory and the `/Users/denis/Programming/Golang/src/backend/src` directory.

I would personally recommend moving your api.jwt.auth folder to `/Users/denis/Programming/Golang/src/api.jwt.auth` to keep your source all in one area, but having two different directories in your GOPATH as suggested above will work too.

To understand GOPATH better, you can simply type `go help gopath`.  Also a quickstart is [here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)

Comment: Thanks a lot, approach with 2 paths in GOPATH helps me! Is it bad practice to do that, should I move my source code as you mentioned above?

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice; just not common.